WAGMIv2: hex_.replace is not a function in useWriteContract
I tried to write a contract but I got this error: "hex_.replace is not a function".
Could you tell me the solution about this.
My code:
    const abi = [
        {
            type: "function",
            name: "sendToL1",
            stateMutability: "nonpayable",
            inputs: [{ name: "_message", type: "bytes" }],
            outputs: [{ type: "bytes32" }],
        },
    ];

  const { data: hash, error, isPending, writeContract } = useWriteContract();

  async function submit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const message = formData.get("message") as string;
    writeContract({
      abi,
      address: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000008008",
      functionName: "sendToL1",
      args: [stringToBytes(message)],
    });
  }

Error:
TypeError: hex_.replace is not a function
    at padHex (chunk-P7TG7TXV.js?v=70f73695:162:20)
    at encodeBytes (chunk-ACCTJPS5.js?v=70f73695:2872:16)
    at prepareParam (chunk-ACCTJPS5.js?v=70f73695:2793:12)
    at prepareParams (chunk-ACCTJPS5.js?v=70f73695:2767:25)
    at encodeAbiParameters (chunk-ACCTJPS5.js?v=70f73695:2755:26)
    at encodeFunctionData (chunk-ACCTJPS5.js?v=70f73695:3641:56)
    at simulateContract (chunk-ZZWOZNZF.js?v=70f73695:1068:20)
    at chunk-CWWJZU6N.js?v=70f73695:1750:22
    at simulateContract2 (chunk-CWWJZU6N.js?v=70f73695:2648:37)
    at async writeContract2 (chunk-CWWJZU6N.js?v=70f73695:2901:42)

